# Getting index of TabItem using data binding

Tags: wpf, binding

I binding ItemsSource of TabControl, when I added new TabItem, It is visible but not selected. I want to change SelectedIndex of TabControl but I dont know how I can get this index from recently created TabItem.
Please help.

Comment: Do you want to select the currently added TabItem or you want the Index of it for another purpose... ??

Comment: Select currently added TabItem

Comment: See my answere below.. its should help you..sorry if there are typos

Comment: The title of this Q is misleading. I want to bind to the index of the tab item, just as the title says. But the Q is not about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this, assuming `tabControl` is the control id.

```
 tabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

`SelectedIndex` is public (Get and Set) property of `TabControl`. Read more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.aspx).

You can read more about data bidning @

- [Use data binding in tab control](http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2009/10/05/use-data-binding-in-tab-control/)
- [Wpf tutorial binding to a tabcontrol](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-binding-to-a-tabcontrol)

Hope this works out.

Comment: I using MVVM pattern so I don't have instance of TabControl.

Comment: From [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/27185566-1637-490b-819e-252b955025b8/) try setting `IsSynchronisedWithCurrentItem="true";`

Comment: Good solution but not suitable for MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MVVM Then

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MySource}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MyItem,Mode=Twoway}" 
            SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=MyIndex,Mode=TwoWay}"></TabControl>
```

Here the properties that are bounded are all in view model and firing propertyChnaged (I leave its implememntation on you)..

because we have added `Mode=TwoWay` then if you add a new item to your collection  in your view model you can set it as `MySource.Add(<itemInstance>);MyItem=<iteminstance>;` It will get selected on view and you will also get the SelectedIndex if you require.

Comment: MyItem=<iteminstance>; I cant do that, becouse I using template on TabControl so <iteminstance> is not TabItem and I have an error.

Comment: MyItem's type should be the type of items held in MySource

Comment: I use Template so I must create own class to binding.

Comment: @Colder u r Templates will be used at view level.... At viewModel level you will be having a collection if some Model Class like `ObservableCollection<Person>` which is binded to `TabControl` so you `TabItems` will be created based on the number of persons added to teh collection... so your person added is you tabItem...

Answer (score 1):

`tabControl.SelectedIndex = tabControl.Items.Count -1;`

Or you could bind the `SelectedItem` and assign the new `TabItem` as the `SelecteItem`. 
That would be cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

TabItem has IsSelected dependency property.
You just do this

```
tabItem.IsSelected = true.
```

I believe that the new tab will be selected for you.

Or

you can make ItemContainerStyle for the TabItem control and you and bind the IsSelected with the TabItems.

```
<TabControl x:Name="_tabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding .....}">
<TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding TabSelected}"/>

    </Style>
</TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;

tabControl1.SelectedIndex=tabControl1.items.count-1;